# Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

I am trying to import records from an old database into a new database clean database.
I have setup the new database to have IDENTITY Primary keys, however I want to insert the same values as the original database.

in SQL I did :

```
set IDENTITY_INSERT plans on
```

I am using LINQ to SQL and I have turned off Auto-generated columns but I am still getting this error:

```
Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table 'Plans' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.
```

but it IS ON

Answer (score 3):

The `identity_insert` setting is local to the database session. You have to use the same database connection when you set it, as when you do the insert.

Comment: can you set it in LINQ anyway?

Comment: Good one @Guffa. michael, maybe you just needed to re-create your table in LINQ to SQL or EF model. You could have posted your solution.